# Ollydbg "Single step event at ntdll - Press shift+f8 to pass execution...."?

Tags: events, exception, ollydbg, ntdll

I had olly 2 Beta which was working fine but it misses some old features of Olly 1 like Call stack window and also it doesn't works with any plugins. So i decided to switch to Olly 1.10.

The problem is, whenever i load any program, it says "Single step event at ntdll - Press shift+f8 to pass execution to the main program" or something like that. When i press the key combination, it says "Debugged application was unable to process execution". I've tried passing "00000000-FFFFFFFF" as exception range and tired all the "Ignore Exception" options but the application crashes.

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Download the latest OllyAdvanced plugin from here: http://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.75 - and enable "64-bit compatibility fix" in Plugins->Olly Advanced->Additional Options

If this doesn't help, a workaround may be NOT ignoring the exception and NOT pressing Shift+something, but just pressing F9 when the error occurs.